# What are the fundamental limits effecting transmitter and reciever size in wireless energy transmission?

Tags: radio-frequency

In my simple understanding of the problem thus far, I see that one limit is that the field strength must be limited so that the air isn't ionized.  Another limit is a limit of the radiation pattern of the transmitting antenna.  The radiation pattern of an antenna can, in the best case scenario, produce a tight cone shape, but no matter what, there is always reduced field always fans out.  Waves with higher frequency have the potential for higher energy per unit area.

How is my understanding?  What else do I need to consider?

Thanks!
Adam

Comment: See [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_module#Main_factors_affecting_RF_module_performance), if it is helpful I can post a full answer.

Comment: This is an interesting question. There are three length scales here;  size, separation, and wavelength. If you make a 2D plot with (choose any) two ratios as the axes, you can plot various effects as regions in the plot.

Comment: Why would you even worry about a little bit of ionized air? One can alway raise the pressure and use $SF_6$. :-) For visible light the atmospheric ionization threshold is somewhere around $10^{13}W/cm^2$. I don't think your cell phone charger or even your electric car wireless chargers are anywhere close to that. :-)

Comment: @uhoh: My little brother said he doesn't think this whole thing is a good idea because he thinks people won't want to get cooked or sliced in half in case something goes wrong when I try to drive my semi-truck from point A to B without virtually no energy storage, just wireless power transmission.  Nevertheless, I am curious about this plot you propose.

Comment: If nobody else makes a plot, I'll give it a try. I try not to eat meat because I don't like cooking and slicing *anyone* in half, even cows! Side effects are less methane and less deforestation = less CO2 as well.